# Phusion Passenger will not obey my RailsEnv setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a custom environment, "demo", and no matter what I've tried, Rails still loads my development environment.

Here's the entry in my vhosts file:

```
<Directory /var/www/demo/public>
  SetEnv RailsEnv demo
  RackEnv demo
  RailsEnv demo
  AllowOverride all
  Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

I have all three settings there just to test, but nothing seems to work. I restarted Apache, and I made an entry for demo in my `config/environments` directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been able to solve it with a bandaid, but still would love to know the best way to do this. I hardcoded this line in my application.rb file:

    Rails.env = ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new('demo')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it to work by using

```
SetEnv Rails_Env demo
```

instead of

```
SetEnv RailsEnv demo
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you... where I host my application (alwaysdata.com), I use Passenger and the RailsEnv is set in a `.htaccess` file at the root of my Rails application

```
SetEnv RAILS_ENV production
SetEnv GEM_PATH ~/gems/
```